# Phantom UEFI Boot Options

Tags: multi-boot, uefi

A while ago some phantom boot options (boot options for a generic device that isn't plugged in) started appearing, such as "Hard Drive" and "DVD/CD Drive" Its extremely annoying and I haven't been able to find a solution to clear these nonexistent entries. I've tried resetting the cmos and booting after unplugging all drives and this doesn't make the phantom entries go away. For all I know it might even be slowing down my boot time too. The motherboard is a Maximus VII Formula. Not sure what other details I can give to help. I unfortunately just created this account so I can't post a picture

Answer (score 0):

These entries exist because the UEFI has its CSM enabled. Disable an option in UEFI called something like "Legacy", "BIOS boot" or "CSM." The option might be worded like "Use UEFI only" for example.

Note that this will disable legacy booting which means certain things like some older bootable CDs may not work anymore. This likely isn't a problem for the OS as its clearly installed as UEFI.